# How to combine two select statements in c++

Tags: c++, sql, performance, sqlite

For an assignment, I'm looking to make my code faster. I'm using the sqlite3 c++ API to perform tasks in order to eventually build an r-tree and b-tree.

I am doing the assignment's tasks correctly, but unfortunately it's extremely slow. For my question, I'll first show simple mock tables, then show a simple flow of my program.

Simplified table schema's:

```
areaTable (id int, closed int)
middleTable (nodeid int, areaid int)
nodeTable (id int, x float, y float)
```

The flow of my program is as follows:

**query1**

```
SELECT id FROM areaTable WHERE closed = 1;
```

Using query1 I save the resulting id's into an vector array (we'll call it query1ResultsArray).
Then using sqlite3_prepare_v2 I prepare a new select query:

**query2**

```
SELECT MIN(x), MIN(y) 
FROM nodeTable
WHERE id IN
    (
    SELECT nodeid 
    FROM middleTable 
    WHERE areaid = ?
    );
```

The idea of query 2 is that we find will find the minimum values of the nodes that get grouped together by middleTable and areaTable. I **bind** individual results from query1 into query2 using a for loop like the following:

```
prepare query2
begin transaction (not sure if this helps)
for (auto &id : query1ResultsArray) {
    bind(id)
    step(stmt)
    x = column 0
    y = column 1
    cout << "INSERT INTO ...."
    reset(stmt)
}
end transaction
finalize(stmt)
```

This solution appears to work. It get's the proper results I need to continue with the assignment's tasks (building insert statements), but it's very very slow. I doubt the professor expects our programs to be this slow.

This was context for my question. The question itself is essentially:

**Am I able to combine my two select statements?** By combining the select statements I would be able to circumvent the constant binding and resetting which I hope (with no knowledge to back it up) will speed up my program.

I've tried the following:

```
SELECT MIN(x), MIN(y), MAX(x), MAX(y) 
FROM nodeCartesian
WHERE  id  IN 
    (
    SELECT nodeid 
    FROM waypoint 
    WHERE  wayid  IN 
        (
        SELECT id 
        FROM way 
        WHERE closed = 1
        )
    );
```

But this gets the minimum of all nodes since they don't get properly grouped together into their respective 'areas'.

P.S. I am dealing with a 2D r-tree, so I know what I wrote isn't correct, but I just wrote what I'm having difficulty with. Also, I tried researching how to apply inner joins to my statement, but couldn't figure out how :(, so if you think that may help my performance as well, I would love to hear it. Another thing is that query1 deals with 2+ million rows, while query2 deals with approximately 340,000 rows, and I estimated that it will take about 1 day for query2 to finish.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at the "JOIN" SQL keyword?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure about your schema; however, I think that something like this by including a group by your area should do it

```
SELECT m.areaid, MIN(n.x), MIN(n.y), MAX(n.x), MAX(n.y)
FROM
    nodeCartesian n
    INNER JOIN waypoint wp ON n.id = wp.nodeid
    INNER JOIN way w ON wp.wayid = w.id
    INNER JOIN middleTable m ON n.id = m.nodeid
WHERE
    w.closed = 1
GROUP BY
    m.areaid
```

Note: calling a SELECT query multiple times in a loop is a bad idea, because each call has a great overhead which makes it really slow. Making a single query returning all the relevant rows and then looping through them in code is much faster.

Comment: I was hesitant of giving too much away as this is an ongoing assignment, but you almost guessed my assignment's schema (which makes me nervous a bit), so the schema is, more accurately:     
nodeCartesian(id, minX, minY, maxX, maxY),     way(id, closed),        waypoint(nodeid, ordinal, wayid)

So unfortunately I can't group by n.areaid.

Comment: You must join the middleTable to get the areaid I presume. I adjusted the query.

Comment: Thank you. You answered one of my implicit questions of whether or not the multiple SELECT calls was slow. I think I need to possibly ask my main question in a shorter way without the fluff and more of the information in it. At a later date. I'm making your answer the accepted answer because you helped me with your note and showed me how to implement the inner joins. I'm not sure what the Stackoverflow etiquette is on this kind of thing, so if I did something wrong or unacceptable just let me know.